# How do I build a cross currency basis swap pricer using implied levels generated from fx forwards?

Tags: fx

How can I construct a simple calculator to imply the cross-currency basis (with sides) from the FX forward and interest rate markets, at maturities under 1y?

Depending on liquidity the market in Australia can get quite out of line between the two.